# How to resolve CSS module error in angular 12

Tags: css, angular, angular12

In my angular application after added below the font i am getting Module error.How to resolve this issue in angular.

app.component.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: GraublauWeb;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url("./assets/font/GraublauWebBold.woff") format("woff");
}
```

Error:

> ./src/app/app.component.css - Error: Module Error (from
> ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> D:\project\star\src\app\app.component.css:7:43: Can't resolve
> './assets/font/GraublauWebBold.woff' in 'D:\project\star\src\app'

Answer (score 3):

Use it like this, correct path:

```
@font-face {
font-family: GraublauWeb;
font-weight: bold;
src: url("/src/assets/font/GraublauWebBold.woff") format("woff");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you check that "assest/font" exist?

Try "assets" instead of "assest":
src: url("./assets/font/GraublauWebBold.woff") format("woff");
or
src: url("/assets/font/GraublauWebBold.woff") format("woff");

Comment: assets?????????????

Comment: Yes, "assets". Can you navegate to your webapp, and check if you have something like 'D:\project\star\src\app\assets\font' with fonts inside?